# Vue.js mounted function not accessing component properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm not very new to Vue.js which is probably why I feel like I've been running mad all morning :). While creating a component, which I usually do, quite frequently, in this case, I had to initialize Google Maps within the `mounted` function, which seems like the right place to do that. In the `mounted` function, I would access the `id` property of a nested input field and attach an event listener to it. Pretty simple right?

Well, I figured that when I try to use the component multiple times on my page, I'm somehow accessing the same (seemingly shared) `this` variable within the `mounted` function.

Not sure why exactly this happens and/or if it's a feature but to make it even weirder, the props yield correct values within the template. (and within the methods as well)

**Component Definition**

```
<template>
  <div class="LocationInput">
    <input
      type="text"
      :id="id"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'LocationInput',
  props: ['id'],
  mounted() {
    console.log('Component object representation ==> ', this)
    console.log('ID ==> ', this.id)
  }
}
</script>
```

**Using my component...**

```
<template>
  <div class="MyTravelApp">
    <LocationInput id="id1"/>
    <LocationInput id="id2"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LocationInput from './components/LocationInput';
export default {
  components: { LocationInput }
}
</script>
```

What I get at the end of the day is the correct id values in the template but in my console, the exact same object and id are logged as you can see below. Notice how the `_uid` property is the same thing for both.

[image: Console Output]

To make matters even worse, after modifying the `this` variable in the `mounted` function, while inspecting, I observed that the second component has that property modified as well. So they are essentially sharing the same object, which is extremely weird.

I would like to know if anyone has had similar issues and how to deal with it.

Comment: Why pass the prop in the using component part by, id="id1" instead of :id="id1"?

Comment: You have a template open tag for your first template close tag.

Comment: @M.Suurland That's because I'm passing it as a string.

Comment: Try adding a `:key` directive with the value the id.

Answer (score 0):

[No self-closing tags for components](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1036).

> Vue templates need to be valid HTML. There are no "self closing tags"
> in HTML5, it's an XHTML syntax which is now outdated and you should
> never use it.

(Later note:)

> FYI self-closing tags works in 2.0 as long as you don't use in-dom
> templates.

You may also be having an issue with [camelCase vs. kebab-case](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case). The snippet below behaves as expected.

```js
Vue.component('locationInput', {
  template: '#location-input-template',
  props: ['id'],
  mounted() {
    console.log('Component object representation ==> ', this._uid)
    console.log('ID ==> ', this.id)
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#my-travel-app'
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<template id="location-input-template">
  <div class="LocationInput">
    <input type="text" :id="id">
  </div>
</template>

<div id="my-travel-app">
  <location-input id="id1"></location-input>
  <location-input id="id2"></location-input>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah! Let me try that.

Comment: Doesn't still work. I'm also using `.vue` files so I shouldn't have that problem ideally.

Comment: Hey @RoyJ, thanks for this. I can see this works but still doesn't work for me. I changed my syntax to use kebab case. I'm using single file components. Not sure if that might be contributing to the issue.